# Slow Start in ECN supported TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, switch-statement, router, congestion-control

Assume a host joins with others to send packets to one host. All hosts connect to a switch that support ECN marking.

If the time it joins is when network congested and switch marks every packets incoming.

But this host is only begin at Slow-Start phase and when it send first packet, it gets ECN marked.

So, is this host still in Slow-Start or move to Congestion Avoidance phase?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, ECN is not a congestion control algorithm itself, but is a function(maybe there is more accurate expression... anyway).

Therefore, it depends on the mechanism of a ecn supported congestion control algorithm.
For example, in the regime of DCTCP, if its cwnd if smaller than ssthresh, the flow still be in slow-start phase.